# How to use regular expressions with resources in Laravel 4

Tags: php, routes, laravel, laravel-4

If we create a simply route with Laravel 4 we can use where to set a regular expression for each param. passed in the URI. For example:

```
Route::get('users/{id}',function($id){
    return $id;
})->where('id','\d+');
```

For every get request second param. must be digits. Problem comes when we create resources, if we use `->where()` it throws an error about this is not an object.

I've tried to place where into a group, as an array as third param. in the resource but has not worked.How could we use the power of the regular expressions with the power of Laravel 4 resources?

Comment: Don't *think* you can. You should be doing checks to make sure the supplied value exists in the database anyway so making sure it's a number only or only contains alphanumeric characters isn't *always* required.

Answer (score 0):

He Joss,

I was going mad with the same question, so I did some research. All I could come to is the following conclusion: you do not need this method. In each of your controller methods you can specify your default values after each argument:

```
public function getPage(id = '0', name = 'John Doe'){
```

Next to this you can do a regular expression check, and a lot of other checks with the laravel validator like this:

```
        //put the passed arguments in an array 
            $data['id'] = $id;
            $data['name'] = $name;

    //set your validation rules
            $rules = array(
                    "id" => "integer"
                    "name" => "alpha"
        );
            // makes a new validator instance with the data to be checked with the given 
            // rules
    $validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);

            // use the boolean method passes() to check if the data passes the validator
    if($validator->passes()){
            return "stuff";
            } 

            // set a error response that shows the user what's going on or in case of            
            // debugging, a response that confirms your above averages awesomeness

            return "failure the give a response Sire"; 
}
```

Since most of the validation are already in the [options list](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#available-validation-rules) of laravel you might not need the regular expression check. Yet it is an option (regex:pattern).

My theory behind the none existence of the where() method in the controllers is that the method offers you the opportunity to do validation within you Route file. Since you already have this possibility in your controller there is just no need for it.